# Android Layout background alpha

Tags: android, background

Hi I have a layout which I'm using to fill my page and I have to set a background image held in my `drawable folder` in that layout.

I want to then set the `alpha value` of the image to something quite low almost make the image like a water mark.

my xml looks like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/main_background" >
```

As you can see I have assigned an id to the layout

I thought in my oncreate I could do something like this?

```
View backgroundimage = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);
backgroundimage.setAlpha(80);
```

This is not working however I suspect its because I'm trying to cast the background as a `View` what should I cast it as?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try to use:

```
Drawable.setAlpha();
```

You should do something like this:

```
View backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable background = backgroundImage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

Comment: Although this method works, it appears that to get the original state or 100% alpha, you might need to use a 0-1000 scale.  So if you are trying to get a button to look 50% alpha, you might actually have to setAlpha(200) instead of setAlpha(50)...at least using API 19 on a Button...so resetting the button back to it's original look, I had to setAlpha(1000)...

Comment: 100% opacity equals to 255, not 1000

Comment: because it's so convenient to calculate a % of 255!

Comment: When you check `setAlpha()` method, it's parameter is annotated with range: `@IntRange(from=0,to=255) int alpha`.

Answer (score 36):

If you want to set alpha in xml then u can try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#CC000000" >
```

> first 2 digits are used to set alpha here alpha is 80% next 6 digits
>   for color code

Hence, alpha is set in hexadecimal coding. FF = 100% and 00 = 0%, thus 80% is not 80 in hexadecimal, for more standard values see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239853/1724097) post.

Answer (score 2):

You Can Set Alpha for Drawables not Views ! You Can get background as a drawable and do like this :

```
View backgroundimage = (View) findViewById(R.id.background);
backgroundimage.getBackground().setAlpha(80);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This on your LinearLayout

> android:background="#92000000"