# Problems in ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

My listview is transparent. I changed it. But still it has a slight transparency. How to disable it as the text aren't viisble.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sportsbg">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="310dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFffffff"
    android:divider="@color/lists_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is the sportsbg a transparent background?

Comment: `android:background="#FFFFFF"` and then make sure that your `textColor` in `Textview`  is not white or something near to white.

Comment: @danidee, it doesn't matter as its the background of an activity and not listview

Comment: @danidee No its a dark background. so i need the list to be whitish colour.

Comment: show the screenshot @Ruch1234

Comment: u sure about the list isn't *empty* which u used to populate `ListView`

Comment: @HulkKiller I uploaded the photo.

Comment: @Ruch1234, you want solid color for the list?

Comment: `ListView` is transparent background coz u have set alpha `FF` in xml remove that transparency will be gone [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587323/android-layout-background-alpha/19427884#19427884)

Comment: @kaushik I removed it and also added it. the same effect comes.

Comment: @HulkKiller yes i want a solid colour.

Comment: try this `android:background="@android:color/white"` or you can put a solid colored pic and use it as a background like `android:background="@drawable/your_pic"`

Comment: @Hulk Killer Still the same

Comment: if so uninstall the app from device or emulator. Clean your project and run.

Comment: Show your java file, might be doing something there dynamically.

Comment: it works now. Thanks guys. The problem was there was an layout large which contains the transparency code. and i was testing with a large layout device.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the background of your listview to

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

where as

```
android:background="#FFffffff"
```

specifies a alpha.