# How to set transparency of a background image Android xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have put an image in as the background of my android application with the following line of code:

```
 android:background="@drawable/background"
```

I now want to make it transparent by 40% but how is this possible within the xml file? My exm file is shown below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:alpha="0.6"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textColor="#292421"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="This Android application is used to track and record the movements of a person throughout the university of ulster, Magee Campus. The tracking phase of the application can only be initiated whilst within the campus and off campus tracking is unavailable at this moment in time."
    android:textColor="#292421"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E6E6FA"
        android:onClick="tracking"
        android:text="@string/tracking_service" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E6E6FA"
        android:onClick="help"
        android:text="Help" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 49):

You can set the alpha property:

```
android:alpha="0.4"
```

via code :

```
yourView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

only the background :

```
yourView.getBackground().setAlpha(120);  // here the value is an integer not float
```

Comment: I have found a problem with using this as my text on this page is also faded which I don't want, is there another way of doing this?

Comment: How do I do this if the background image is embedded into the root constraint layout itself?

Answer (score 40):

If you have set an image as background then

```
 android:alpha="0.x"
```

will cause entire screen (child views) to fade.
Instead you can make use of

```
android:backgroundTint="#80FFFFFF"
android:backgroundTintMode="src_over"
```

to fade only the background image without affecting the child views.

Comment: backgroundTint and backgroundTintMode require API 21 and higher.

Comment: Best answer, this answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @Mike do you find a solution for API lower 21?

Answer (score 24):

It can be done using custom drawable. Its a very old post but thought I should answer, might be helpful for someone.

1. Create a drawable xml resource with **bitmap** as the root say **bg.xml**.
2. set **android:src="@drawable/background"** to the image which you want as the background.
3. set **android:alpha="0.4"** to any value between 0 to 1 as per the required opacity.
4. now set the background of the root layout as newly created drawable xml resource i.e., **bg.xml**. This will only change the opacity of the background image of the layout without effecting opacity of the child elements of the layout.

Resources : 
bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/background" android:alpha="0.4"/>
```

This is how your layout will look now :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textColor="#292421"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="This Android application is used to track and record the movements of a person throughout the university of ulster, Magee Campus. The tracking phase of the application can only be initiated whilst within the campus and off campus tracking is unavailable at this moment in time."
    android:textColor="#292421"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E6E6FA"
        android:onClick="tracking"
        android:text="@string/tracking_service" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#E6E6FA"
        android:onClick="help"
        android:text="Help" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 16):

you can create a layer-list resource and set it to background property of your view (layout)

background_image_with_alpha.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:alpha="0.2"
            android:src="@drawable/xxxxxx"
            android:gravity="fill">

        </bitmap>
    </item>

</layer-list >
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you don't want opacity to affect elements on the screen, just the background image

Comment: Great way to effect only the background's opacity AND not mess up your code with layout stuff.

Answer (score 3):

set in your xml file

```
android:alpha="0.4"
```

which will be varies from 0 to 255.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:alpha="0.6"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="30dp"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:text="Welcome"
android:textColor="#292421"
android:textSize="17sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="This Android application is used to track and record the movements of a person throughout the university of ulster, Magee Campus. The tracking phase of the application can only be initiated whilst within the campus and off campus tracking is unavailable at this moment in time."
android:textColor="#292421"
android:textSize="17sp" />

<LinearLayout
 android:background="@drawable/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#E6E6FA"
    android:onClick="tracking"
    android:text="@string/tracking_service" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp" >

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#E6E6FA"
    android:onClick="help"
    android:text="Help" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: alpha fades the text on the page as well so is it possible to use another way of doing this!

Comment: Yes you can use it dynamically.Want to set for whole application?

Comment: I just want it to fade the background image and the text to be clear which will be ontop of the image! So how would I set it to only effect the image?

Comment: So have you set background for layout in which ur TextView and imageview will be or only imageview?

Comment: It will be affected because u have set background for parent layout in which ur TextView s also include. if you want to ignore them then u have to set background for ur other LinearLayout which is child layout.

Comment: I don't understand, could you edit my question to show me what you mean?

Comment: the background image is only in that linear layout and does not cover the full background?

Comment: In your case if you set full background then TextView will be affected.

Comment: I will have to find another way of fading the image

Answer (score 3):

You can use alpha property 
android:alpha="0.5"; (Between 0 and 1 )

Comment: this is best way

Answer (score 2):

You can use `alpha` property (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:alpha) for your `View`:

```
android:alpha="0.4"
```

Comment: alpha fades the text on the page as well so is it possible to use another way of doing this!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Drawable.setAlpha();

```
View backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background_image);
Drawable background = backgroundImage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this line in your .xml file 
`android:background="#ddxxxxxx"`
replace the xxxxxx with any color you want.
refer https://alvinalexander.com/android/how-background-image-behind-translucent-opaque-textview for more details.