# how to set Blur/dim background

Tags: android

I'm trying to set blur background image. Android studio projects are available. But I'm using eclipse. So any one help me to how to set blur image programmatically?

Comment: hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406961/how-to-set-transparency-of-a-background-image-android-xml-file

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this to set your opacity

```
android:alpha="0.5"
```

**OR**

```
 yourView.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

Comment: possible to set image like gaussian blur?

Comment: see this if it might be of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067955/fast-bitmap-blur-for-android-sdk

Answer (score 2):

To set transparency level of the view to make it dim

View class have [setAlpha(float alpha)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29) method which is Added in API level 11.

> So from API level 11 and after you can use that method in xml and
>   class too.

Using xml `android:alpha` set float value between `0 to 1`

**For before and after api level 11(for all)** third party library is available for alpha and other things also.

NineOldAndroid

```
ViewHelper.setAlpha(View yourview,float alpha)
```

What else you can do to make image blure effect is, convert image to bitmap with blur/dim effect. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21052060/1140237)