# Android is showing the background black

Tags: android, android-layout, transparent

I have background of my `LinearLayout` a `PNG` file with `1440x2560` resolution `8 alpha` with some transparency. When I run it, `Android` displays the whole background of the `LinearLayout` black and only shows `ImageButtons` and `TextViews`.

I read that this is possibly because of the transparency but how can I fix it when I already have:

```
<LinearLayout
android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

as my background and I can't set it transparent from there. Also I get

```
 E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
```

[image]

Comment: THere's nothing behind your linear layout. When there's nothing behind it, it will display white or black depending on the device. So you're transparent, but you're transparent over a black image.

WHat effect did you want? If you wanted to show transparently on top of the previous activity, you need to set your Activity's theme to do so.

Comment: Yes, I want to show transparently on top of the previous activity. But the problem is that the rectangle that is the actual background (non transparent part) shows black as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android   for how to create a transparent Activity.  As for the image itself not showing-  it may just be too big, if you're seeing render OOM errors.  I'm not an expert on Open GL, but I seem to remember some devices not doing much over 1400x2000.  Try a small image, see if it works, then try to debug from there?

Comment: Your PNG is too big, resize it and make it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `transparent` of course which you already added it.

You can try to add this :

```
android:alpha="0.4"
```

**Check this out too:** [How to set transparency of a background image Android xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406961/how-to-set-transparency-of-a-background-image-android-xml-file)

Comment: This really seems the way to do it but it does not work. Also the non transparent part would be made transparent this way.